# How to continue the code on the next line in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to type the mathematical forumla in VBA code which many lines. I would like to split it into many lines. How do I do it?

For example:

```
U_matrix(i, j, n + 1) = k * b_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (4 * hx * hy) * U_matrix(i + 1, j + 1, n) + (k * (a_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / hx ^ 2 + d_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (2 * hx)))
```

is very long. would like to split it.

Tried this:

```
U_matrix(i, j, n + 1) = k * b_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (4 * hx * hy) * U_matrix(i + 1, j + 1, n) 
_+ (k * (a_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / hx ^ 2 + d_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (2 * hx)))
```

But not working.. Need some guidance on this..

Comment: Does it matter if the "_" is on the previous line?

Comment: No, it does not matter. A line continuation is a space character followed by an underscore character (_), then a line termination character (the Enter key)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To have newline in code you use `_`

Example:

```
Dim a As Integer
a = 500 _
  + 80 _
  + 90

MsgBox a
```

Comment: Is there something that can be used for array initialization? If there's a newline after "_", it gives an error:
  Dim StringPairs As Variant  <newline>  
  StringPairs = [ {"abc", "def"},   _<newline>
  {"123", "456"}]

Comment: It should be `" _"`, not `"_"`.

Comment: On the contrary: if I want to combine 2 separate lines of code into 1 line, is there a way? (like `;` in a lot of languages)

Comment: @JackeyOL regular colon `:` is used for that in VBA. For example `Dim a As Integer: a = 500 + 80 + 90: MsgBox a`

Answer (score 29):

```
(i, j, n + 1) = k * b_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (4 * hx * hy) * U_matrix(i + 1, j + 1, n) + _
(k * (a_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / hx ^ 2 + d_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (2 * hx)))
```

> <sub>[From ms support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141513)</sub>
>
> To continue a statement from one line to the next, type **a space**
>   followed by the line-continuation character [the underscore character
>   on your keyboard (_)].
>
> You can break a line at **an operator, list separator, or period**.

Answer (score 14):

In VBA (and VB.NET) the line terminator (carriage return) is used to signal the end of a statement. To break long statements into several lines, you need to

> Use the line-continuation character, which is an underscore (_), at the point at which you want the line to break. **The underscore must be immediately preceded by a space and immediately followed by a line terminator** (carriage return).
>
> (From [How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx))

In other words: Whenever the interpreter encounters the sequence *`<space>`*`_`*`<line terminator>`*, it is ignored and parsing continues on the next line. Note, that even when ignored, the line continuation still acts as a token separator, so it cannot be used in the middle of a variable name, for example. You also cannot continue a comment by using a line-continuation character.

To break the statement in your question into several lines you could do the following:

```
U_matrix(i, j, n + 1) = _
     k * b_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (4 * hx * hy) * U_matrix(i + 1, j + 1, n) + _
     (k * (a_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / hx ^ 2 + d_xyt(xi, yi, tn) / (2 * hx)))
```

(Leading whitespaces are ignored.)

Comment: Upvoted for explanation in addition to answer. Commenting to add that there is an additional step if you're trying to break up a string. If you want to have a string on two lines you need to close the quote; add an ampersand(&), space, and underscore(_); and start the new line with another quote. Remember to include a trailing space or leading space or you'll end up with a word mash where the two strings join.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to insert this formula `=SUMIFS(B2:B10,A2:A10,F2)` into cell G2, here is how I did it.

```
Range("G2")="=sumifs(B2:B10,A2:A10," & _

"F2)"
```

To split a line of code, add an ampersand, space and underscore.

Comment: I'd just add that this particular method is only required in VBA if you are splitting in the middle of a literal string. Otherwise, you just need a space and an underscore.