# Multi-Line comments Invalid inside Enum

Tags: excel, enums, scope, vba

Situation:

I noticed today, when commenting my code, that a single line comment inside of an Enum is ok, but a multi-line comment, with a line break, throws the error:

> Invalid inside Enum

For example, the following works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum testing
    'My comment text
    Value1 = 1
    Value2 = 2    
End Enum

Private Sub test() 
    MsgBox testing.Value1 
End Sub
```

But changing the comment to multi-line in the following, fails:

```
Public Enum testing
    'My comment _
     text
    Value1 = 1
    Value2 = 2  
End Enum
```

More specifically, it seems the presence of the line-continuation character is the issue as I can happily perform:

```
Public Enum testing
    'My comment
    'text
    Value1 = 1
    Value2 = 2
End Enum
```

I looked up the error [Invalid inside Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/invalid-inside-enum) at MSDN:

> Not all types are valid within an enumeration definition. This error
>   has the following causes and solutions:
>
> You tried to specify a string or some other invalid type as the value
>   of an Enum member. The constant expression used to specify an Enum
>   member must evaluate to type Long or another Enum type.

That didn't really illuminate the issue for me so I looked for explicit cases where you can't use a line-continuation character and found the following in [How to: Break and Combine Statements in Code (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code):

> You can't continue a comment by using a line-continuation character.
>   The compiler doesn't examine the characters in a comment for special
>   meaning. For a multiple-line comment, repeat the comment symbol (') on
>   each line.

Now, while more experienced hands might look on smiling knowingly, I was surprised to discover this. I have merrily (a.k.a ignorantly) used the line-continuation for multi-line comments without problems for years e.g.

```
Private Sub test()
    'This is another multi _
     line
End Sub
```

So, it seems, to me, that the compiler must either:

1) Employ some context sensitive logic to the handling of the line-continuation character, e.g. inside a `Sub` or `Function` , or indeed `Module` scope is OK but inside `Enum` is not.

2) Be updated in some parts and not in others.

**Question:**

What is the reason behind this apparent inconsistency and the fact that I seemingly can use a line-continuation character for comments in many cases?

Additional references:

1) [How to continue the code on the next line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854386/how-to-continue-the-code-on-the-next-line-in-vba)

Comment: IMO this inconsistency could have to do with the prevalent effect of underscores to hide Enum member names from object browser and intellisense (after encasing such member names in brackets [], as leading underscores aren't allowed here) at the expense of full comment support. So possibly any underscore would be identified as an invalid naming attempt regardless of the place it occurs. - Cf. Chip Pearson's  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx and an interesting technique at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/interesting-technique-error-handling-enumeration-vba-chip-pearson

Comment: @T.M. Thanks. I will have a look.  I am not that advanced so I can't say I fully understand your comment but I will try to. This bit "prevalent effect of underscores to hide Enum member " means?

Comment: My comment is based on supposition, as I don't know the actual programming logic of the related basic libraries.  Maybe this is a theme worth to be treated by another of our SO gurus (possibly @Mat's Mug with insight of VBA DLLs and libraries). - BTW appreciated your question, as it allows me to learn: I wouldn't have found the second link reference showing a very interesting technique of error handling via `Enum` validation without your question (see https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/interesting-technique-error-handling-enumeration-vba-chip-pearson).

Comment: If you name a `Enum` member e.g. `[_First]` the underscore character plays an important role - or even *prevailent* role over pure line breaking - by "preventing those names from appearing in Intellisense (but you need the square brackets [..] to keep the compiler from complaining about the leading underscore character), so you won't see them when you're coding and use the enumeration"

Comment: Pretty sure @Mat's Mug would have come across it. Thanks for the explanation :-)