# "else without if" getting this error in excel vba

Tags: vba

I am getting the error "else without if" in the code below.
Can someone please help?

```
For I = 2 To LR5
   If (Range("Ae" & I).Value = 5 & Range("x" & I).Value = 2 & Range("y" & I).Value = 2) Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "30000"
   ElseIf (Range("Ae" & I).Value = 5 & Range("x" & I).Value = 4 & Range("y" & I).Value = 4) Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"
   ElseIf Range("Ae" & I).Value = "29" Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "10000"
   ElseIf Range("Ae" & I).Value = "30" & Range("x" & I).Value = "4" Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "80000"
   ElseIf Range("Ae" & I).Value = "30" & Range("x" & I).Value = "2" Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "50000"
   ElseIf Range("Ae" & I).Value = "17" & Range("x" & I).Value = "2" Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"
   ElseIf Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS11" Then Range("AH" & I).Value = "80000"
   ElseIf Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS11+RRUSA2" Then Range("AH" & I).Value = "80000"
   ElseIf Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS12" Then Range("AH" & I).Value = "120000"
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Move everything after `Then` to a new line.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR: You need to move everything after `Then` to a new line.

---

In VBA, one-line-`If`-statements have the following characteristics:

- They don't have `End If`, **ever**.
- They **must** be written *entirely* as one line.<sup>1</sup>

For example:

```
If someCondition Then DoSomething
If someCondition Then DoSomething Else DomeSomethingElse
If someCondition Then DoSomething(x) Else If anotherCondition Then DoSomething(y) Else DoSomething(z)
```

However, one-line-`if` should be used exclusively for short statements. It's generally not a good idea to use it when you have `Else` (let alone `Else If`). So, in the code block above, the second and third examples are not recommended. Instead, you should write your `If` statements like this:

```
If someCondition Then
    DoSomething (x)
Else If anotherCondition Then
    DoSomething (y)
Else
    DoSomething (z)
End If
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can, of course, break statements into multiple lines using the `_` though. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22854386/4934172) for more.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

in a boolean expression you want to use `AND` instead of `&`

furthermore in such a convoluted case a `Select Case` block is much more readable:

```
For I = 2 To LR5
    Select Case True
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = 5 And Range("x" & I).Value = 2 And Range("y" & I).Value = 2
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "30000"
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = 5 And Range("x" & I).Value = 4 And Range("y" & I).Value = 4
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = "29"
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "10000"
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = "30" And Range("x" & I).Value = "4"
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "80000"
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = "30" And Range("x" & I).Value = "2"
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "50000"
        Case Range("Ae" & I).Value = "17" And Range("x" & I).Value = "2"
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"
        Case Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS11"
            Range("AH" & I).Value = "80000"
        Case Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS11+RRUSA2"
            Range("AH" & I).Value = "80000"
        Case Range("E" & I).Value = "RRUS12"
            Range("AH" & I).Value = "120000"
        Case Else
            ' put code to handle the case when no preceeding conditions are met
    End Select
Next
```

and here's another way of *translating* the same `If Then Else If` of yours into a `Select Case` block:

```
For I = 2 To LR5

    Select Case Range("Ae" & I).Value

        Case 5
            Select Case True
                Case Range("x" & I).Value = 2 And Range("y" & I).Value = 2
                    Range("ah" & I).Value = "30000"
                Case Range("x" & I).Value = 4 And Range("y" & I).Value = 4
                    Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"
            End Select

        Case "29"
            Range("ah" & I).Value = "10000"

        Case "30"
            Select Case Range("x" & I).Value
                Case "4"
                    Range("ah" & I).Value = "80000"
                Case "2"
                    Range("ah" & I).Value = "50000"
            End Select
        Case "17"
            If Range("x" & I).Value = "2" Then Range("ah" & I).Value = "60000"

        Case Else
            Select Case Range("E" & I).Value
                csse "RRUS11", "RRUS11+RRUSA2"
                    Range("AH" & I).Value = "80000"

                Case "RRUS12"
                    Range("AH" & I).Value = "120000"

                Case Else
                    ' you may want to put code to handle the case when no preceeding condition is met
            End Select

    End Select

Next
```