# VBS upgrade from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem solving the expected, line number or end of line in the following.

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemDirectory Lib "KERNEL32" Alias "GetSystemDirectoryA" ()
    (ByVal Buffer As String, ByVal size As Longptr) As Longptr
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to continue the code on the next line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22854386/11683)

Comment: On top of that, your declaration is wrong. The second parameter is `As Long`, and so is the return value. You don't mindlessly replace all `Long`s with `LongPtr`s, only those that are pointer-sized.