# Writing long array in VBA code, how to handle line jumps?

Tags: excel, vba

Making VBA code which removes company acronyms from their names. Example:

- Apple Inc. -> Apple
- Tesla inc. -> Tesla

The following line of code was tried:

`valuesToRemove = Array("Inc","SRL","Ltd","Limited","etc.")`

Because I have a long list of those incorporation acronyms (more than 100 - its for many countries), it seems the VBA editor is not accepting line jumps.

If the values are all one next to an other in the `Array()` function it works. But I can not fit those in one single line. The line must jump to accommodate many values. I tried editing the Array but with no luck.

[image]

What would be a solution here?

Comment: put a `_` before you move to the next line.

Comment: Thank you.. This seem to work. The must be a space preceding the underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** - Add a new value in the array on each line

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim valuesToRemove(3) As Variant
    valuesToRemove(0) = "SRL"
    valuesToRemove(1) = "S. R. L,; o LTda. (Solo Chule)"
    valuesToRemove(2) = "LTD"

End Sub
```

**Option 2** - [How to continue the code on the next line in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854386/how-to-continue-the-code-on-the-next-line-in-vba)

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim valuesToRemove() As Variant
    valuesToRemove = Array("SRL", _
                        "S. R. L,; o LTda. (Solo Chule)", _
                        "LTD")
End Sub
```

**Option 3** - [Creating an Array from a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

Write these values in an excel range and then read the range and convert it to an array. This is probably the best option, as a user is able to change it from their Excel, without entering the code:

[image]

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim valuesToRemove As Variant
    valuesToRemove = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A3"))
                        
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the suggestions.
I took the Option 2 approach of using an underscore to jump lines.